# jquery scrolling on the page

Tags: jquery

I want create this effect:
- I have on website a few divs with position absolute(only first is visible) and on some event I want that window will scroll to the second div(than to the third,4th..)

What jquery method is best for it?Because only animate isn't cool I think maybe margin-left or some scroll

Thanks for help.(if you know some website where is this effect please write me it)

Comment: What is wrong with using `animate`?

Comment: nothing but maybe there are better effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really aren't any other ways to make the page scroll without using javascript.  You can use anchor tags to snap to a location, but if you're looking for a smooth scroll, javascript is the way to go.  Using jquery ui to animate the scroll is your best bet for easy implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a *content slider* plugin.
Since you have used the *jQuery* tag, I guess you are using this library. So, you should have a quick look at:

- [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/)
- [Awkward Showcase](http://www.awkwardgroup.com/sandbox/awkward-showcase-a-jquery-plugin/)